# Can discriminant polynomials become perfect powers on hyperplanes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, classical-invariant-theory

Let

$$\displaystyle f(x) = a_d x^d + a_{d-1} x^{d-1} + \cdots + a_0.$$

Consider the *discriminant* of $f$, denoted by $\Delta(f)$, defined as

$$\displaystyle \Delta(f) = a_d^{2d-2} \prod_{i < j} (\theta_i - \theta_j)^2,$$

where $\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_d$ are the roots of $f(x) = 0$ (over some algebraic closure, say).

It is well-known that $\Delta(f)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2d-2$ in the coefficients $a_d, \cdots, a_0$.

We say that a homogeneous polynomial $F \in \mathbb{C}[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$ of degree $m$ *ramifies completely on a hyperplane* if there exists a hyperplane $P$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $F |_P$ is a perfect $k$-th power for some $k > 1$ dividing $m$ (as a polynomial). For example, the cubic polynomial $F(x,y,z) = x^3 + yz^2$ ramifies completely on the lines (hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^2$) $y = 0, z = 0$.

For $d = 2$, we have that $\Delta(f) = a_1^2 - 4 a_2 a_0$ ramifies completely on $a_2 = 0, a_0 = 0$. Does this happen for $d > 2$? That is, does there exist $d > 2$ and a hyperplane $P \in \mathbb{P}^d$ such that $\Delta(f) |_P$ is a perfect $k$-th power, for some $k | 2d - 2$?

Comment: I added the algebraic-geometry tag. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $d \geq 2$, there are hyperplanes on which $\Delta_d$ ramifies, but for $d \geq 3$, it never ramifies **completely**. I guess there are many proofs of this fact, let me give one based on projective duality.

First note that $\Delta_d$ parametrizes polynomials of degree $d$ having a multiple root. Let me give a geometric interpretation of $\Delta_d$. Let $X = v_d(\mathbb{P}^1) \subset \mathbb{P}(S^d \mathbb{C}^2)$ be the $d$-th Vernoese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1$. The equation $\Delta_d = 0$ gives in the dual projective space $\mathbb{P}(S^d \mathbb{C}^2)^*$ the variety which parametrizes singular hyperplane sections of $X$. This variety is known as the **projective dual** of $X$.

For any $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^N$, which is irreducible, the reflexivity Theorem tells you that $(Z^*)^* = Z$ and for any $z \in Z_{smooth}$, the tangency locus of $z^{\perp}$ with $Z^*$ is identified **as a scheme** to $\mathbb{P}(N_{Z/\mathbb{P}^N,z}^*)$.

Going back to your situation, we have $X = v_d(\mathbb{P}^1) \subset \mathbb{P}(S^d \mathbb{C}^2)$ is smooth, its projective dual $X^* \subset \mathbb{P}(S^d \mathbb{C}^2)^*$ is the hypersurface which equation is $\Delta_d = 0$. You want to know if there exists $x \in \mathbb{P}(S^d \mathbb{C}^2)$ such that $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ is completely non-reduced. This is equivalent to saying that the reduced space underlying the singular locus of $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ is  equal to the reduced space underlying $(x^{\perp} \cap X^*)$.

Two cases occcur:

1) if $x \notin X$, then $x^{\perp}$ is not tangent to $X^*$ (this is because $(X^*)^*= X$). Hence the singular locus of $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ has codimension at least one in $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ and the equation defining $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ can't be a $k$-perfect power.

2) if $x \in X$, then $x^{\perp}$ is tangent to $X^*$ (this is again because $(X^*)^*= X$). Since $X$ is smooth, the reflexivity Theorem ensures that the tangency locus of $x^{\perp}$ with $X^*$ is **scheme-theoretically** a hyperplane in $x^{\perp}$. As a consequence, the singular locus of $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ is generically scheme-theoretically a hyperplane. Now, if $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ was a $k$-perfect power, then the fact that the singular locus of $x^{\perp} \cap X^*$ is generically scheme-theoretically a hyperplane in $x^{\perp}$ would imply that $k=2$ and $\deg \Delta_d =2$. This is only possible if $d=2$.

As far as non-complete ramification is concerned, the above argument shows that for any $x \in X$, the equation of $x^{\perp} \cap \{\Delta_d = 0\}$ can be written as $L^2Q$ where $L$ is a linear factor and $Q$ a polynomial of degree $2d-4$ which is not a power.

Comment: What you wrote here is really interesting... is it possible to use this to describe the locus, for a given $d$, such that $\Delta_d(f) = \square$?

Comment: can't read the square. You want to describe the locus such that $\Delta_d(f) = ???$?

Comment: the square is actually just a square, i.e., I want to look for the locus on which $\Delta_d(f)$ is equal to the square of some polynomial

Comment: For example, when $d = 4$ the locus contains a countable union of lines. An example of such a line is given by $a_3 = a_1 = 0, a_4 = a_0$, giving rise to polynomials of the shape $a_4 x^4 + a_2 x^2 + a_4$. The discriminant is identically a square on this line.

Comment: I don't know if this second question is well-posed. If you take different lines, the system of coordinates vary with the lines you take and this doesn't look obvious how to relate one square to the other.

Comment: The question could be "what is the locus, in the appropriate Grassmannians, such that the restriction of the discriminant is a square on each linear spaces parametrized by this locus?" This seems to be a much more difficult question. Indeed, the theory of projective duality is quite rich, precisely because there is a duality.

Comment: If you go to any Grassmannians, the duality is much harder to formulate (Chow forms) and has less powerful consequences. But the Chow forms have been studied by many people. You may first have a look to the book "Discriminants, resultants and multidimnesional determinants" by Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85523/discussion-between-stanley-yao-xiao-and-libli).